# List of functions: Apply additional argument only to those functions who can take it

Tags: r

I have a list of functions, most of which take the same additional argument (`na.rm = TRUE`).

I want to add a function which doesn't take this argument (`length`). Is it possible to apply the additional argument only to the functions which can take it? I thought of using `...`, but I am not really sure how to apply it, and if this is possible at all.

I am using `lapply`, but happy with any options, also beyond base R.

```r
x <- c(1:10,NA)

# working example only with functions that take the extra argument

show_stats <- function(x) {
  funs <- list(mean = mean, sd = sd)
  lapply(funs, function(f) f(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}
show_stats(x) 
#> $mean
#> [1] 5.5
#> 
#> $sd
#> [1] 3.02765

# sadly not working, because length() only takes one argument
show_stats <- function(x) {
  funs <- list(mean = mean, sd = sd, n = length)
  lapply(funs, function(f) f(x, na.rm = TRUE))
}

show_stats(x)
#> Error in f(x, na.rm = TRUE): 2 arguments passed to 'length' which requires 1
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the safest way to do this but you can use `tryCatch` wherein if there is an error you return `f(x)` without any additional arguments.

```
show_stats <- function(x) {
  funs <- list(mean = mean, sd = sd, n = length)
  lapply(funs, function(f) tryCatch(f(x, na.rm = TRUE), error = function(e) f(x)))
}
show_stats(x) 

#$mean
#[1] 5.5

#$sd
#[1] 3.02765

#$n
#[1] 11
```

Comment: Thanks! That's neat. I am also not sure if 'very safe', but certainly absolutely ok for my example!!

Answer (score 6):

**1)** The question is not clear on what is expected as output for `length` but if the question is how to remove the NAs regardless of whether the function takes an `na.rm` argument or not then just remove the NAs first.

```
show_stats2 <- function(x) {
  funs <- list(mean = mean, sd = sd, length = length)
  lapply(funs, function(f) f(na.omit(x)))
}
```

**2)** Another possibility which allows the functions to have arbitrarily varying arguments is the following.  Each function is defined as a simple formula with whatever arguments are appropriate.  This uses `fn$` from gsubfn to transform a formula to a function.`

```
library(gsubfn)
show_stats3 <- function(x) {
  funs <- list(mean = ~ mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
               sd = ~ sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
               length = ~ length(x))
  fn$lapply(funs, function(f) fn$identity(f)(x))
}
```

**3)** Here is a variation of (2) which requires that you write the word `function` but is similarly flexible:

```
show_stats4 <- function(x) {
  funs <- list(mean = function(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
               sd = function(x) sd(x, na.rm = TRUE),
               length = length)
  lapply(funs, function(f) f(x))
}
```

**4)** Yet another variation is to use `Curry` from the functional package:

```
library(functional)
show_stats5 <- function(x) {
  funs <- list(mean = Curry(mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
               sd = Curry(sd, na.rm = TRUE),
               length = length)
  lapply(funs, function(f) f(x))
}
```

Comment: Sorry I made the question not clear enough. length is in order to get the sample number. removing NA may be an option, of course.

Comment: See show_stats3 which is completely flexible and is not specific to na.rm and can have any combination of arguments. Also show_stats4.

Comment: that's pretty badass. Sorry to have so quickly accepted @ronakshah 's answer, you would definitely also have deserved it

Answer (score 2):

You can try `partial` from `purrr` as well, not sure if you are intended this way. You may also want to check possibly, safely and quietly from purrr, they might useful in some cases

```
func_factory <- function(x){
  partial(x, na.rm=T)
}

show_stats <- function(x) {
  funs <- list(mean = func_factory(mean), 
               sd = func_factory(sd), n = length)

  lapply(funs, function(f) f(x))
}

show_stats(x)
```

**Output:**

```
> show_stats(x)
$mean
[1] 5.5

$sd
[1] 3.02765

$n
[1] 11

>
```